# Print out square format java

Tags: java, string, format, string-formatting

I need to print out a square of hashes in the following type of format:
    ####
    ####
    ####
    ####
I would like to have an input which will change the dimensions of the square based on a user's choice. Any idea what is the best way to create a reusable method for this? My problem lies in the fact that I konw how to print a string of characters but changin this into a square leaves me baffled. Maybe I could use a loop for this as well?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - StackOverflow is not a "Write my code for me" site.

Comment: as for a first question and clearly a beginner, I think voters who downvoted should be ashamed.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
public void printRectangle(String str, int width, int height) {
   for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
       for (int x=0; x<width; x++) {
           //if (x > 0) System.out.println(" ");
           System.out.print(str);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Example

```
printRectangle("#### ", 4, 4);
```

would produce

```
#### #### #### ####
#### #### #### ####
#### #### #### ####
#### #### #### ####
```

And

```
printRectangle("#", 4, 4);
```

would produce

```
####
####
####
####
```

Comment: I like your answer a lot but I'm not sure he wanted the extra space between hashes.

I thought he wanted

####
####
####
####

A simple commenting out of line 4 would do it :)

Comment: well, then he would simply have to remove the `if` statement. Whether or not your speculation is right, this is a trivial thing to do.

Comment: in any case, I amended the code (leaving the `if` statement in comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
int size_of_square = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < size_of_square; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < size_of_square; j++){
        System.out.print("#");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Didn't test but I hope this gives you a good enough idea.

If you want to like have a string "square" that just holds all the string in one you could just instead of printing do something like.

```
square += "#"   //hash for square
square += "\n"  //newline
```